# Compare the new array with the previous one

Tags: php

I have an array with 4 elements

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So far I am printing several arrays, all with different elements in each array, to a limit set by me.

```
for($i = 0; $i<=100; $i++){//...
```

Output so far:

```
[11, 22, 32, 44]
[22, 33, 44, 45]
[12, 24, 25, 31]
[15, 16, 31, 41]
[22, 33, 44, 45]//already exist
[11, 22, 32, 44]//already exist
...
```

How can I compare an outgoing array to the next one going out and delete the new one if is equal to the previous array?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You need to provide us with your complete attempt, example data, expected results and what results you're currently getting.

Comment: in_array([22, 33, 44, 45], [[11, 22, 32, 44], [22, 33, 44, 45]]) will give you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a key for an array with the help of `implode()` and have a `set` array which has this key. If key is already present, then the current array in iteration is a duplicate one, else it's a new one. Remember to sort the current array as the order of the numbers matter here for proper key check.

```
<?php

$arr = [
        [11, 22, 32, 44],
        [22, 33, 44, 45],
        [12, 24, 25, 31],
        [15, 16, 31, 41],
        [22, 33, 44, 45],
        [44, 22, 32, 11]
    ];


$set = [];    
foreach($arr as $curr_array){
    sort($curr_array);
    $hash = implode("|",$curr_array);
    if(isset($set[$hash])) echo "Duplicate",PHP_EOL;
    else{
        print_r($curr_array);
        $set[$hash] = true;
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/EXXRu

Comment: Perfect! thats it! I also thank the other comments! Sir, until there are no more duplicates which cycle and condition could I use? it's possible?

Comment: @DavidConcha What do you mean by `until there are no more duplicates`?

Comment: make all possible combinations between arrays

Comment: @DavidConcha Didn't understand. Can you give an example?

Comment: given the following array for example [0,0,0,1] make all possible outputs:
[0,0,1,0]
[0,0,1,1]
[0,1,0,0]
...

Comment: @DavidConcha You will need to ask that as a new question.

Comment: Okay, you really helped me a lot, I will try some things. Thanks again!